# Data alignment in store instruction

Tags: assembly, arm

In ARM assembly, I have data across registers `r3 - r9`. I want to store them back to memory using `stm` instruction starting from address which I have in `r0`

Instruction `stm r0,{r3-r9}` would put data from the registers right next to each other.
But what I want is to have a 16-byte gap between the stored values, e.g do something like:

```
str r3,[r0]
str r4,[r0,#16]
str r5,[r0,#32]
str r6,[r0,#48] 
...
```

Is this possible with the `stm` instruction or is there some shortcut trick?

Comment: The `STM` instruction lets you specify whether the destination address should grow downwards or upwards, but not what the stride should be (it'll be the size of a register, i.e. one word). So you'll likely have to use some alternative solution like the one you suggested yourself.

Comment: Thaks for a comment.. Then maybe is there some trick rather than 8 STRs?

Comment: That's doable with NEON & interleaved load & write-back. (well, 7 registers is a bad number though.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The STM instruction [lets you specify whether the destination address should grow downwards or upwards](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0231b/Cacdibae.html), but not what the stride should be (it'll be the size of a register, i.e. one word). So you'll likely have to use some alternative solution like the one you suggested yourself.

For example:

```
str r3,[r0]
str r4,[r0,#16]
str r5,[r0,#32]
....
```

or

```
; Slightly simpler since it's obvious that the stores are spaced 16 bytes apart,
; altough it doesn't preserve the original value of r0 like the above version
str r3,[r0],#16
str r4,[r0],#16
str r5,[r0],#16
....
```

Comment: The first *form* is limited to **4k** or 256 entries for a 16 byte stride.